# Map colour mode "random" works in Google Earth but not in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, geospatial

I'm working on an application that displays server-generated KMLs on Google Maps. I am responsible for business layer and back-end, but now I'm facing a problem with the extjs based front end. I would like to ask a KML question about colouring of placemarks to see if it's related to Google Maps or my application. Since I don't have many details about the front end development, I'll ask my collagues about additional code/implementation details when needed.

What I do know right now is that we use the following Javascript libraries:

- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.10&sensor=false
- http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js
- http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ProjectedOverlay.js

My goal is to generate a KML that displays on a Google Map and shows a set of geographic areas, each represented by a Polygon and each randomly coloured. I just need that adjacent polygons don't show the same colour. I have found that `MapColorMode.RANDOM` from my Java KML library should solve the problem.

So I created a KML based on the following fragments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xal="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0">
    <Document>
        <Style id="randomColour">
            <PolyStyle id="randomColour">
                <color>ffffffff</color>
                <colorMode>random</colorMode>
                <fill>1</fill>
                <outline>1</outline>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <Folder>
            <styleUrl>randomColour</styleUrl>
            <Placemark>
                <name>0</name>
                <styleUrl>#randomColour</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <extrude>1</extrude>
                    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>...</coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>7</name>
                <styleUrl>#randomColour</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                    <extrude>1</extrude>
                    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>...</coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            [...]
        </Folder>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

(data is obfuscated more for brevity rather than for privacy)

Here it is how it displays on Earth (good):

[image: Google Earth]

And how it displays on Google Maps (bad):

[image: Google Maps]

The question is: why does it display white on Maps? Is it a problem with Maps capabilities, Javascript library, KML file or something else? What can I do to achieve the same viewing on Maps too?

Comment: Maybe I'm being stupid, but your randomColour style is white.  Then each of your Placemarks is using that colour... do you actually have multiple styles with differing colours that you're applying to each PlaceMark?

Comment: @duncan you're not stupid. According to Google APIs, the random colour mode uses the provided colour as upper bound of a linear progression. Using a different colour than white causes Google Earth to render a random linear colour (for each channel) between black and that colour.

Comment: How are you displaying the KML? Are you using KmlLayer or [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) If you are using geoxml3 (you are including the script), random color mode _should_ work, it not working would be a bug.

Comment: @geocodezip as said by Ela, it is supposed to not work as per official Google documentation

Comment: Only if KmlLayer is being used.  If geoxml3 is used, it _should_ work, I haven't had a chance to test it yet though.

Comment: [example with random using geoxml3 (kmz branch)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_simple_linkto.html?type=m&filename=VoterDistricts_random.xml), a quick [test with the polys branch doesn't seem to work](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_simple_linkto.html?type=m&filename=VoterDistricts_random.xml)

Comment: Created an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/issues/detail?id=94)

Comment: The issue has been fixed.  Do you have a version of your KML available for testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Google API](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps),  **`<randomColor>` is not supported!**

The Link also provides you a list of all supported KML tags...

Also keep in mind that Google sets some limitations of how many items on the map will be rendered with styles. if you have too many items in your KML it will fall back to the default.

But in your case, its because of randomColor.

Comment: They are not using KmlLayer, they are using geoxml3 which does support the random colorMode.

Answer (score 0):

random color mode didn't work in [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) [(the polys branch)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_simple_linkto.html?type=m&filename=VoterDistricts_random.xml), that was a bug, created an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/issues/detail?id=94) and fixed it.

it always worked in the [kmz branch](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_simple_linkto.html?type=m&filename=VoterDistricts_random.xml)

Both the examples above now work.